# BeautifulSoup4 table scraping when no unique class - Learning

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am still trying to learn scraping websites. I came across this case related to my work:
website: https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/consolidated-sanctions-list-data-files

Screening sanctioned lists. I am trying to get the 3 CSV hrefs as you see in the:

- CONS_PRIM.CSV
- CONS_ADD.CSV
- CONS_ALT.CSV

I know I can just import the csv from the link itself in python but I want to enhance my scraping knowledge. All the "tr" has the same class name "text-align-left". So I thought of looping over the main "table" element with class "ms-rteTble-1" and then narrow down my choices to those that end with CSV, but my loop doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate all the help

```
source_html = requests.get('https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/consolidated-sanctions-list-data-files').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_html,'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class' : 'ms-rteTable-1'}):
    print(i.a['href'])
```

I am getting only the first file which is .zip, how can I do it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to offer a different approach. Why not go for all anchors that have `.csv` in them?

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/consolidated-sanctions-list-data-files'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find_all(lambda t: t.name == "a" and ".CSV" in t.text)
print([a["href"] for a in soup])
```

Output:

```
['https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_prim.csv', 'https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_add.csv', 'https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_alt.csv', 'https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_comments.csv']
```

As for your code, you're looping over a single item, which is your soup, that contains a table. You'd have to loop through all the rows, to get all `href` attributes.

To fix that, try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/consolidated-sanctions-list-data-files'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find('table', attrs={'class': 'ms-rteTable-1'})

for item in soup.find_all("th"):
    anchor = item.a
    if anchor:
        print(anchor["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/consall.zip
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/cons_advanced.xml
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/consolidated.xml
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_prim.del
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_add.del
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_alt.del
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_comments.del
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_prim.ff
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_add.ff
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_alt.ff
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_comments.ff
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_prim.csv
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_add.csv
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_alt.csv
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_comments.csv
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_prim.pip
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_add.pip
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_alt.pip
https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/consolidated/cons_comments.pip
```

Comment: thanks mate for the solution and correcting my code. I looped over it thinking it will return list of all arguments that match the criterion. but you are right it return single object, hence it is logic to get back only first file....

Answer (score 1):

Just another way, using xpath selector

```
import lxml.html
import requests
response = requests.get('https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/consolidated-sanctions-list-data-files', stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
tree = lxml.html.parse(response.raw)
tree.xpath("//tr[5 <= position() and position() <= 7]//a/@href")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. this is completely new way for me, i will read more about it. I adjusted it to be tree.xpath("//tr[13 <= position() and position() <= 15]//a/@href") and got list of CSVs